# reviewing an edit of one of my own answers

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review

Somebody suggested (and obviously bad of course (smily wink) ) change to one of my answers I gave in reply to their question.

Should I be the one reviewing this edit?

It was that another reviewer already disagreed (and flagged) the edit , but still is this proper and just?

Comment: You can find some details about suggested edits here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179257/what-happen-if-other-users-make-edit-on-someones-answer/ One of the things mentioned there is: *The owner of a post may cast a binding vote to accept or reject any modification of their post.*

Comment: This is probably irrelevant to the general question, but I suppose the suggested edit you mentioned is [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/187543).

Comment: yes it was, n the mean time i have edited my answer a little bit in the suggested direction (but the answer became longer not shorter :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You should always review edits to your posts, even after they have been approved or declined.

You are the author of the post, and you should take a look and decide whether or not someone is changing your tone, or what you wanted to say; or if they actually improve that.

My personal preference is usually to decline edits that modify content in any way (sans typos), and I will sometime go as far as reverting them. But I recall once that an edit was suggested that was actually in place, and it was declined by two users. I accepted that edit, and made it myself after all (or at least commented that it shouldn't have been rejected, I don't know).

**The point** is that you should always review edits to things your name is signed on. Even if you have no say on the edit. But in this case you have a big say as to whether or not the edit is valid, and you should probably exercise that vote to cast veto when needed.